# How to use systemd to run a script only on process bad exit instead of graceful one

Tags: linux, systemd

I configured systemd to run a system devised of several services and targets.

I wish to run a script that creates a notification if a service in the system crashes. The problem is that my system has several dependencies including a restart of several services in a specific order if one of the services crash and I can't use `ExecStopPost` because then all the services notifies of a crash even if they were shut down by the systemd because another service has crashed.

Any attribute or other way to run a script if a service crashes (and only if it crashed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but [`OnFailure`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#OnFailure=) or [`FailureAction`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#FailureAction=) may be what you are looking for.